# Running SAS code in EG without triggering prompts associated with the program

Tags: sas, prompt, enterprise-guide

When associating a program to one or several prompts, is it possible to make SAS trigger those prompts only when the program is run in its totality (by right-clicking on it - or on its parent Process Flow - and choosing "Run...")?

This would allow submitting simple lines of code (like `%put &someVar;`) from within the program (with F3 or Run Selection) without being bothered by the prompts (which don't impact the results of this type of operation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible (at least until V4.2) - The only course of action is to remove prompts from individual program whilst you are running your tests and put them back on again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, but you can set a default value for the prompt and just click ok on the prompt then in your code assign the value

```
%let someVar = someValue;
```

to the parameter(s) as desired, if different from the default value in the prompt.